# Can't register agent Already exists

Tags: ubuntu

root@server1:~# bluetooth-agent 0000

Can't register agent

Already Exists

Can someone please tell me how to unregister the agent?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to do rfcomm connection to connect Bluetooth headset device to my Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1):

For future references:
This may be because you have another bluetooth-applet is running. See my prompt:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps aux | grep applet
pi        2497  0.0  3.5 102476 31640 ?        S    10:25   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet
pi        9011  0.0  0.2   3564  1828 pts/2    S+   15:22   0:00 grep --color=auto applet
```

You need to kill the applet program.